# Prometheus OR Operator

Tags: sql, prometheus

I am trying to run this query in Prometheus. But I need to add "OR" operation in envoy_cluster_name and add another cluster name, so incase a change of cluster name it picks the correct one.

Really appreciate if you can tell me how to use OR operator here.

```
https://prometheus.test.com/api/v1/query_range?query=sum(increase(envoy_cluster_rq{kubernetes_cluster='test_cluster', envoy_cluster_name='cluster_https___api_test',service='test'}[1m]))&start=2020-03-25T08:00:00Z&end=2020-03-27T08:11:00Z&step=1m
```

I have tried the following, but it gives separate outcomes.

```
https://prometheus.test.com/api/v1/query_range?query=sum(increase(envoy_cluster_rq{kubernetes_cluster='test_cluster', envoy_cluster_name='cluster_https___api_test| test123',service='test'}[1m]))&start=2020-03-25T08:00:00Z&end=2020-03-27T08:11:00Z&step=1m
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just enumerate cluster names in regexp. For instance the following filter would select time series with `envoy_cluster_name='name1'` and `envoy_cluster_name='name2'`:

```
envoy_cluster_name=~'name1|name2'
```

Comment: Thanks :) Figured it out.  btw Thank you so much. 
Sorry, I can't give you an upvote since my reputations is less than 15.